# Change option tag doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

It might be quite simple and stupid quesion,however
I couldn't make it work to change the option tag dynamically.

```
<select class=select name='' value=''>
    <div id="selecter">
        <option value="">------</option>
    </div>  
</select>
<div id ="test">test</div>
```

in my javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('#smallGenreSelecter').html('<option value="">11111</option>');

    $('#test').html('changed!!');
});
```

Upper one #smallGenreSelecter doesn't work , while lower one #test works though....

Comment: `<div>` inside `<select>` is invalid. And Where is `$('#smallGenreSelecter')` should be `$('#selecter')` according to your markup?

Comment: yeah, thank you for your advice. I understod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select id="smallGenreSelecter">
        <option value="">------</option>
</select>
<div id ="test">test</div>

$(function(){
    $('#smallGenreSelecter').html('<option value="">11111</option>');

    $('#test').html('changed!!');
});
```

The #something in the jQuery selector is matched against an element's ID attribute. You shouldn't put divs inside select elements.

Comment: Thanks,I understood that div in select tag is invalid.